# Angular no realiza peticiones a servidor Go

Tags: angular, go

estoy haciendo peticiones de Angular a una Api en Go el problema es que al realizar las peticiones no realiza ninguna ya importe el httpmodule en el app.module.ts tengo una petición así:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TiendasService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  CargarTienda(txt:String) {
    
    
    return this.http.get('localhost:3000/')
  
  }
}
```

y en el servidor Go tengo lo siguiente:

```
func Enrutador() {
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

router.HandleFunc("/", rutaInicial).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/cargartienda", cargartienda).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/TiendaEspecifica", TiendaEspecifica).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/Eliminar", Eliminar).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/id/{id}", BusquedaPosicion).Methods("GET")
fmt.Println("servidor escuchando en puerto : 3000")
http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)

}

    //------> metodo main
    func main() {
        Enrutador()
    }


func rutaInicial(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Si funciono el servidor")
    fmt.Println("envia peticiones ")
}
```

como se puede ver solo pido que imprima si recibe las peticiones y si las realizo por postman si consume la Api no se si debo de generar algun permiso para que la pueda consumir desde angular

Comment: ¿Te has suscrito al observable devuelto por el servicio? A diferencia de las promesas, los Observables no hacen nada mientras no los observes

Answer (score 2):

Si haces las peticiones desde postman sin usar credenciales podrás hacerla desde cualquier otro sitio, sea CLI, usando algún cliente Curl, etc, por lo que este no será el problema.

No soy experto en angular pero pienso que cuando haces la siguiente petición y la devuelves:

```
return this.http.get('localhost:3000/')
```

Esta devolviendo un [`observable`](https://angular.io/guide/observables).

Intenta utilizar `subscribe` (método que usa internamente angular de la librería [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)), de esta manera puedes obtener el contenido de la llamada:

```
return this.http.get('localhost:3000/').subscribe(response => console.log(response.text()))
```

Comment: Yo no tocaría el método del Service, es el Component el que debería suscribirse al Observable devuelto por el Service